# RSpec/Ruby verify a value exists in text field

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

For example purposes, lets use google. Let us also assume in the search bar on google we enter texts that reads, "hello". Lastly lets assume the search bar has a save button and we select it to store the data in the field. So now, when you look at the search bar it reads, "hello".

I want to go back into the browser navigate to google and check that text field to ensure it saved as expected - my data that is. I know how to navigate there. But can someone explain to me in Rspec/Ruby how to go into a browser, find the web element you want to verify the value by way of id, name, xpath, etc....and write a command using selenium webdriver with Rspec/Ruby to do so. NO CAPYBARA.

Answer (score 1):

After entering the search term, you can get the value (e.g. `element['value']`) from the text field, and use an rspec [expectation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations) to validate that the correct string has been entered.  For example:

```
#foo_spec.rb

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'

describe "Contrived Example" do

  it "enters a search term" do

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

    element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
    element.send_keys "test string"
    sleep 1
    expect(element['value']).to eq "test string"
    driver.quit

  end

end
```